# Typescript issue referencing item in the object via variable

Tags: typescript

I am rewriting nodejs application into typescript and I am facing an issue I am unable to resolve. I get a cryptic message: 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type' (7053).

Here is an example of my code:

```
function translationFunction(type: string, section: string, language: string) {

  let translations = {
    type1: {
      section1: {
        en: 'I mean this',
        es: 'quiero decir esto'
      },
      section2: {
        en: 'I do not understand',
        es: 'no entiendo'
      },
    },
    type2: {
      section1: {
        en: 'I mean this',
        es: 'quiero decir esto'
      },
      section2: {
        en: 'I do not understand',
        es: 'no entiendo'
      },
    }
  }


    //return console.log(translations.type1.section2.en); - this works
    return translations[type][section][language] // this does not work in typescript but works in javascript

}


translationFunction('type1', 'section2', 'es');
```

I am looking for a solution and I understand this needs to be treated with an interface?

```
  interface translationsInterface {
      [key: string]: any,
  }

  let translations: translationsInterface = {};
```

I have tried for something that would resolve this issue but that does not work for me. I am still getting errors.

Comment: The error is saying that a `string` cannot be used to access a property of `translations`, which you may not have typed, but typescript infers it's type based on the assignment.

Comment: If you wanted `translations[type]` to work you'd need to cast `type` to `keyof typeof translations` -> `translations[type as keyof typeof translations]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`translations:type`

```
type lang = 'en' | 'es'
interface translationsInterface {
  [type: string]: {
    [section: string]: {
      [key in lang]: string;
    }
  }
}
function translationFunction(type: string, section: string, language: lang) {

  let translations: translationsInterface = {
    type1: {
      section1: {
        en: 'I mean this',
        es: 'quiero decir esto'
      },
      section2: {
        en: 'I do not understand',
        es: 'no entiendo'
      },
    },
  }
  return translations[type][section][language]
}
```

> [Exmaple(codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-river-gquv40?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: I have tried your solution, seems like this would work, but I am still getting an error: any
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ en: string; pl: string; es: string; ru: string; }'. Mind you I have amended the lang part to `type lang = 'en' | 'pl' | 'es' | 'ru'`

Comment: Added code to codesandbox